# How to remove footer from some pages dynamicaly using function.php

Tags: wordpress, footer

I am new to wordpress and learning Plugin development, I m creating a custom plugin, which display a list of page-title with check-boxes  in admin section and on checking the selected pages footer should be remove from that pages, now I m facing issue with how to remove footer section?

I dont want to remove footer on single page, so custom template can not be used
I dont want to remove footer using css(like display none)

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wordpress's `remove_action` to help remove unwanted php calls. More on that found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

Something like this:

```
function your__conditional_footer() {
    if( is_front_page() )
    return;
    remove_action( 'theme_before_footer', 'theme_footer_widget_areas' );
}
```

Mind you, the function arguments are theme dependent.

Hope this points close.